# How to run JavaFX on Android

Tags: android, gradle, javafx, javafxports

I try to run a simple JavaFX application on Android. Therefore I read the [javafxports Getting Started Guide](http://javafxports.org/page/Getting_Started) using gradle to build the app, but I got stuck somewhere. I'm able to build and install the app on an Android device using the `installDebug` task of gradle within Eclipse, however, when I start the app I get a black screen. When I extract the `.apk` file it does not contain the jar file of the JavaFX application. I assume the apk should contain the JavaFX application jar-file, but I have no idea how to include it into the `.apk`.

I also tried to use gradle to build the JavaFX application itself (jar-file), which works fine. However, I don't know where to put this jar-file that it can be included into the apk-file. I read I've to put it into a `dist` directory, but I assume this would only be used in Netbeans right? I'm using the Eclipse gradle integration to build the project.

Here is what I tried. Since the JavaFX application is as simple as the HelloWorld sample app and works like a charm, I expect a missconfiguration within my gradle build file.

**build.gradle - to build the apk**

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:2.5.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
ext {
    dalvikSdkHome = getProjectProperty('dalvikSDK')
    dalvikSdkLib = dalvikSdkHome + '/rt/lib'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir file("${dalvikSdkLib}/")
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files ("${dalvikSdkLib}/ext/jfxrt.jar",
                   "${dalvikSdkLib}/ext/jfxdvk.jar",
                   "${dalvikSdkLib}/ext/compat-1.0.0.jar")
}

project.tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex) {
    additionalParameters=['--core-library']
}

String getProjectProperty(String propertyName) {
    project.hasProperty(propertyName) ? project.property(propertyName) : null
}
```

**build.gradle - to build the jar**

```
// Declares binary plugin and its required JavaFX classpath
apply from: "http://dl.bintray.com/content/shemnon/javafx-gradle/0.4.0/javafx.plugin"

// Configures plugin
javafx {
    // Points to JDK and its JavaFX libraries, also declares target runtime JDK
    javaRuntime = getProjectProperty('javaJDKPath')

    // Application name and ID presented by target OS
    appID 'HelloWorldApp'
    appName 'Hello World Application'

    // Main class of application
    mainClass 'helloworld.HelloWorld'

    // JVM arguments, system properties, application command line arguments
    jvmArgs = ['-XX:+AggressiveOpts', '-XX:CompileThreshold=1']
    systemProperties = ['prism.disableRegionCaching':'true']
    arguments = ['-l', '--fast']

    // Keystore credentials for signing JAR
    // Generate key: keytool -genkey -alias release -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keysize 2048
    releaseKey {
        alias = 'release'
        keyStore = file(getProjectProperty('keystoreJKSFile')) // keyStore = file("${System.properties['user.home']}/keystore/keystore.jks")
        keyPass = getProjectProperty('keyStorePassword')
        storePass = getProjectProperty('storePassword')
    }

    signingMode 'release'
    // ...
}

String getProjectProperty(String propertyName) {
    project.hasProperty(propertyName) ? project.property(propertyName) : null
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
javaJDKPath=D:/Java/jdk1.8.0_20
dalvikSDK=D:/Java/dalvik-sdk-8u20b3/dalvik-sdk
keystoreJKSFile=D:/Java/jre1.8.0_20/bin/keystore.jks
keyStorePassword=password
storePassword=password
```

**local.properties**

```
sdk.dir=D:/programme/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917/sdk
```

**And this is my project structure**

```
HelloWorld
-- src\main
    -- java\helloworld\HelloWorld.java
    -- res\
    -- AndroidManifest.xml
-- assets\
    -- javafx.platform.properties
    -- javafx.properties
-- build.gradle
-- gradle.properties
-- local.properties
```

Do I need to use a `dist` directory? Where would I put the jar-file of my JavaFX application that it will be included into the apk-file?

Comment: Perhaps this link will help get you started: http://javafxports.org/page/home and there is also this article: http://www.infoq.com/articles/Building-JavaFX-Android-Apps

Comment: Hey edharned, thanks for your reply. I already visited both sides before. As I remember, the second site uses an old approach by building the app with ant (+gradle). The javafxports Getting Started Guide shows that it's possible to create the app/apk with gradle only. That is what I want (sorry for not pointing that out). I already fixed the issue yesterday and I will post the source code this Friday.

Comment: OK I'm starting to replace Swing with JavaFX. Next project will be porting to Android projects so looking forward to your update.

Comment: @edharned I've posted my source, see answer below. Hope it helps you and all others to get started with JavaFX on Android.

Comment: Thank you. Nobody ever said it was going to be easy

Comment: Note: I've edited the gradle configuration (`build.gradle`) to use the newest version of the android plugin and me.tatarka.retrolambda plugin, since it was updated a few days ago. I received dependecies errors, while refreshing the gradle dependencies. With this update, it is fixed.

The error was: `https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml Required by: MyProjectName:unspecified > me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:2.4.1`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now answering my own question.
The configuration of the gradle setup, as posted in my question, is already running. In my question, I did not show you that I was using a .fxml file for the layout. So the reason why I did not get it running was because the .fxml layout has not been placed at the right spot to be packaged with the apk file (LogCat showed the error `Location Not Found` and I had a black screen on my device).

First of all, **here is a working sample for the HelloWorld.java** (see structure and gradle setup etc. in my question):

```
package helloworld;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

### Run JavaFX on Android using fxml layouts

If you would like to use `.fxml` files, you need to change the structure of your project a little bit. All `.fxml` files, `.css` files, graphics etc. belong into the `resources\assets` directory or subdirectory. This ensures that the .fxml files etc. will be packaged in the apk.

```
HelloWorld
-- src\main
    -- java\helloworld\
        -- HelloWorld.java
        -- MyController.java
    -- resources\assets\
        -- sample_layout.fxml
    -- AndroidManifest.xml
-- assets\
    -- javafx.platform.properties
    -- javafx.properties
-- build.gradle
-- gradle.properties
-- local.properties
```

I did not check, if the `assets` folder which contains the `javafx.platform.properties` and the `javafx.properties` (both from the dalvikVM sdk) is still required. If I check the content of the .apk file, the apk contains both files twice. Seems like the dalvikVM library copies these files automatically.

Note: If you need to check the content of your apk, extract the apk file, then extract the classes.dex which is part of the apk ([see this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file))

**Here is an example using .fxml files:**

*HelloWorld.java*

```
package helloworld;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            URL fxmlFile = getClass().getResource("/assets/sample_layout.fxml");
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlFile);
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            MyController controller = (MyController) loader.getController();
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Sample");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

*MyController.java*

```
package helloworld;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MyController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;
    @FXML
    private URL location;
    @FXML
    private Label label_Counter;
    @FXML
    private Button button_IncrementCounter;
    @FXML
    private Button button_DecrementCounter;

    private static final String OUTPUT_PREFIX = "Counter: ";
    private static int counter = 0;

    @FXML
    void onIncrementButtonPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        label_Counter.setText(OUTPUT_PREFIX + ++counter);
    }

    @FXML
    void onDecrementButtonPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        label_Counter.setText(OUTPUT_PREFIX + --counter);
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert label_Counter != null : "fx:id=\"label_Counter\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'sample_layout.fxml'.";
        assert button_IncrementCounter != null : "fx:id=\"button_IncrementCounter\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'sample_layout.fxml'.";
        assert button_DecrementCounter != null : "fx:id=\"button_DecrementCounter\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'sample_layout.fxml'.";
        label_Counter.setText(OUTPUT_PREFIX + 0);
    }

}
```

*sample_layout.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="helloworld.MyController">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="332.0" layoutY="71.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Label text="Please click on the buttons to increment or decrement the counter:" />
            <Button fx:id="button_IncrementCounter" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onIncrementButtonPressed" text="Increment Counter">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
               </padding>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="button_DecrementCounter" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onDecrementButtonPressed" text="Decrement Counter">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
               </padding>
            </Button>
            <Label fx:id="label_Counter" text="&lt;output-placeholder&gt;">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="20.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Label>
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Hope that helps everyone else getting started with JavaFX on Android.

Answer (score 3):

How to run javafx on android:

1. Download [dalvik sdk](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/downloads/dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3.zip).
2. Go to `samples\HelloWorld\javafx` - it's gradle project
3. Modify location of dalvik-sdk and android-sdk in `local.properties`
   Example on my Windows system:
   `sdk.dir=C\:\\dev\\android-sdk
   javafx.dir=C\:\\dev\\dalvik-sdk`
4. Run `gradlew installDebug` for building and installing apk on device. You also find outputs in `build` folder
5. Launch application on device.(I seen black screen over 10 sec before first launch)
6. Open project in Eclipse or Idea as standart gradle project